# {(x+y)}^2 or (x+y)^2?

Tags: math-mode, typography, braces

This expression is just an example, of course.

My question is: should one always specify the quantity being exponentiated by surrounding it with braces, or is it acceptable to drop those braces?
(Cases in which `\left(...\right)` are used lie outside the scope of my question.)

It seems to me that one should write `{(x+y)}^2` but I do see `(x+y)^2` a lot...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
${(x+y)}^2$ or $(x+y)^2$?
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think there's no need for the first expression, as the second is readable, and if you are between lines (inline math), the second expression won't change interline spacing.

Comment: Definitely `(x+y)^2`.

Comment: There is a clear visual difference between the two renderings, in the position of the exponent.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There is an argument that logically the squaring operation applies to the whole subterm so the `{}` are correct. However it makes the `{}` into a mathord which can affect spacing to adjacent terms and if the subterm is large (but `\left \right` are not used so the brackets are not stretched) then the superscript could float up and become visually detached. So on balance, I think it's better to use the `)^2` form.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${(x+y)}^2 + \sin{(x+y)}^2+{(x+\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}+y)}^2$

$(x+y)^2 + \sin(x+y)^2+(x+\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}+y)^2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The parentheses themselves apply to the whole subterm. So you square the subterm, by setting the exponent to the closed parenthesis.

Comment: @egreg, mathematically yes, but that's not the way TeX views it (as you know:-)

Comment: As both a typophile (type that word and ask Google for spelling suggestions :) ) and an amateur mathematician (if meta) I prefer the second line to the first as I have a preference for closely attaching functions and parenthesis. Just sayin...

Comment: @David: See my answer for another reason why `{}` shouldn't be used.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Yes I should have mentioned the spacing (and lack of line breaking) _within_ the subterm. egreg also mentioned that in a comment to one of the other answers.

Answer (score 31):

There's one major reason against using `{}` that isn't mentioned in the other answers: like `\left(...\right)`, it makes the spacing inside lose its flexibility. Look at this example:

[image: output]

In the first case, the space around the `-` is shrunk to make everything fit into the line, but the `{}` around the parentheses has the effect that the space around the `+` isn't shrunk. In the second case you get even spacing: the shrinking around the `-` is the same as around the `+`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4.9cm}
\begin{document}
$a+{(x+y)}^2$ versus $a+(x+y)^2$
\end{document}
```

Also if you want to prevent a line break, don't use `{}` around the expression, use `\nobreak` instead at appropriate places, like in `(x+\nobreak y)^2`.

Comment: `${...}$` is the correct notation for preventing a line break of an inline formula

Comment: @Herbert: It would be correct if it wouldn't affect the spacing!

Comment: @Herbert if you use `{}` to prevent linebreaking then you have to accept it also freezes horizontal glue. An alternative (but perhaps less convenient way) is to set binoppenalty and relpenalty to 10000

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: sure ...

Comment: IMHO, this argument is problematic: You're suggesting that we should use construct which are semantically inappropriate (i.e. have the ^2 only apply to the right parenthesis) in order to achieve a more pleasing effect in the final output - because of questionable design choices of the typesetting engine, which cannot be otherwise overridden.

Comment: @einpoklum: Well, I'm a mathematician, so I don't see inappropriate semantics here - why should I surround parentheses with braces? I agree that this feature of the typesetting engine is cumbersome, but it's less a design choice than a limitation of computers from the late seventies, when the choice was made.  It would of course be great if LuaTeX  or some other engine would offer better typesetting in such a case.

Comment: You're squaring the parenthesized formula, not the right parenthesis, so the squaring should apply to the { elements of the formula } bunched together... at least that's the way I think of it.

Comment: @einpoklum: What I meant: For me, the parentheses `()` do already bunch the formula together, so there's no need for braces.

Comment: Umm, as we see in [the example in David Carlisle's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104005/5640) - no, they don't. Typesetting-wise, at least.

Comment: @einpoklum: That's what I was saying all the time: math-wise they do. (And typesetting-wise, the output is fine without braces; see Jobobs' answer. Knuth designed the TeX-engine in such a way that you don't have to type braces in order to get nice output.)

Answer (score 18):

Months later...

A relevant passage of the TeXbook (Chapter 16, p129) is the following, which is in agreement with David's answer; I thought I should add it here, for completeness.

> A superscript or subscript following a character applies to that character only; but when following a subformula it applies to that whole subformula, and it will be raised or lowered accordingly. For example,
>
> `$((x^2)^3)^4$` [image]
>
> `${({(x^2)}^3)}^4$` [image]
>
> In the first formula the `^3` and `^4` are superscripts on the right parentheses, i.e., on the `)` characters that immediately precede them, but in the second formula they are superscripts on the subformulas that are enclosed in braces. **The first alternative is preferable, because it is much easier to type and it is just as easy to read.**

(my emphasis)

Comment: Isn’t this ultimately the same as David’s `{(x+\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}+y)}^2` example (the last one)? However, the source is a good one. :)

Comment: The example is similar, yes. Perhaps I should just delete this answer and edit David's to add the reference...

Answer (score 3):

I (**edit** just corrected my belief to) always use `$\left( x + y \right)^2$`, or rather I have a command for the parenthesis and doing `$\paren{ x + y }^2$`. That's semantically a valid thing to do, and I let the TeX engine authors sort out how they want to render it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. To be honest, I consider this *wrong* input.

Comment: The unnecessary usage of `\left` and `\right` and the braces; the `\left`-`\right` pair "freezes" the spacing around `+`, not allowing it to stretch or shrink for helping justification in in-line math; the braces usually put the exponent too high.

Comment: @einpoklum "suitable". that and not adding `{}` around the outside which as discussed in several answers here affects spacing in several ways. Actualy if you don't add `{}` you don't need to check for the following superscript as it will work automatically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok, I'm convinced, correcting accordingly and removing my earlier comments.

Comment: @egreg: `{}` also freezes the spacing, see my answer.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Yes, I know! But in the original formulation of the answer the damage was already done by `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, I see!

Comment: einpoklum: In this particular case, I find some of the comments here hard to follow without being able to see the whole  conversation--including the comments you deleted. That having been said, I don't want to suggest that deleting your own earlier comments that you now consider erroneous is in any way wrong. [Or even that I have any authority whatsoever to say whether it is wrong.]

Comment: Just a little tip: The `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro from the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package allows one to define `\paren` in a flexible (“suitable”) way.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Ping... can you explain why this allows you to define a 'suitable' `\paren`?

Comment: `\paren` from `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}` gives will only freeze the spacing when used with the `*` option (equivalent to `\left..\right`), otherwise it avoids the `{...}` grouping problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike MathML, TeX's math mode makes no attempt to encode the semantics of the typeset math.  Math mode is susceptible to linebreaks, but you can use braces to prevent that: the formula`${(x+y)^2}$` will not break across lines, while `$(x+y)^2$` may.