# Why do the braces in f{\left(x\right)} affect the output?

Tags: spacing, delimiters

Why does `f\left(x\right)` result in more space before the `(` than `f{\left(x\right)}`?

i.e. Why does putting extra braces suppress the space?

Comment: I'm not sure *why* it does that but for your particular example, you should just use `f(x)`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: That comment completely missed the point of my question.

Comment: With the braces, the mathematical properties (`\mathrel`, `\mathop`, etc.) of the parens are lost outside the braces.  Similar to `$a - b$` versus `$a {- b}$`.

Comment: I did not know that! Would you mind please posting those as answers?

Comment: @Mehrdad Svend's comment is right: you shouldn't be using `\left` and `\right` there.

Comment: @egreg: Do you *really* think my ultimate goal here was to produce a document saying "f(x)"? Or do you think I distilled something more complicated into a simpler example to make the problem easier to understand for you?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/xy2-or-xy2

Comment: You should only use `\left`/`\right` contructions if they'll change soemthing for the better. Here, it only adds unnecessary horizontal space.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't think that typing `$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$` would have been so far from minimal and it would have better explained the issue. Why are you taking it so personally?

Comment: @Mehrdad I think you actually missed the point of the comments, which is, in fact, comment. If someone asks why `{\it sniff} and cry` eats some space between `sniff` and `and` he will probably get some comments asking why isn't he using `\textit{sniff}` (which, in my opinion, are beneficial), rather than explaining the italic correction (that would probably be an answer). In short: “*I really freaking **hate** comments like yours*”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` create a "inner formula" with additional spaces around except in scriptsize or smaller or after an opening delimiter or before a closing delimiter. The curly braces put the inner formula into a sub formula with the same spacing rules as an ordinary math atom (`\mathord`).

See package `mleftright`, if you want a solution without additional spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\[
  f \left(\frac xy\right) g =
  f {\left(\frac xy\right)} g =
  f \mleft(\frac xy\mright) g
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I'm asking why one would use `\left` and `\right` there.

Comment: @egreg: That's the disadvantage of a minimal example. The size of the argument does not matter for the horizontal spacing. In real life `x` could be a larger construct like a fraction or whatever.

Comment: That's clear; but I see too many people using `\left` and `\right` when they shouldn't.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thank you, this is a great answer. +1