# What is the reason behind the extra vertical space between the superscript and the subscript in a grouping mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts, superscripts

The distance between the superscript and the subscript for the character of parenthesis, for example, grows in group mode, while the equivalent behavior does not occur for the character of "x", for example, and the distance remains the same! Why is that?

I suppose it's possibly related to the character itself, but I want a convincing reason.

```
${)}^{a}_{b}$\quad $)^{a}_{b}$\\
${x}^{a}_{b}$\quad $x^{a}_{b}$
```

[image: my example]

The output produced using the report class with no options.

[image: my example with border around boxes]

I've depicted my investigations on the matter through the figure. The boxes for each character are drawn in red, and the blue lines are the baselines to the sub- and superscripts, and the green lines are the baselines.

Since the non-paired case, the following:

```
x^{a}_{b}
```

doesn't differ with the followings:

```
^{a}_{b}
{}^{a}_{b}
```

then, which one is more preferable to use?

Comment: The height (and depth) of `)` is greater than those of `x`. You can achieve the same spacing for `x` if you use `{x\mathstrut}^a_b`. `\mathstrut` has the height and depth of `)` without taking any horizontal space. On the other hand you can do something like `{\smash{)}\vphantom{x}}^a_b` to get the spacing of `x` after a closing parenthesis. The last version looks quite odd which is why latex increases the spacing for larger letters.

Comment: @nox That's not the entire story. There is a difference in how `TeX` handles superscripts after `\mathord` and `\mathclose`.

Comment: @campa Oh, you're right. Didn't have this in mind.

Comment: I found this link useful (but the title is very bad!) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/xy2-or-xy2